# Grails forked tomcat execution not working

Tags: tomcat, grails, fork

Grails 2.2.0

I added

```
grails.project.fork.run=true
```

to the Config.groovy file.  On the command line, issued:

```
grails run-app
```

My understanding of the fork ability is that the grails system would exit, leaving tomcat running.  But it never exits.  I have to control+c to leave it, which also kills tomcat.  So I don't believe tomcat is being forked.  Am I missing something?

When doing a run-app I'm seeing a single Java process in both top and Activity Monitor.  I'm also only seeing a single process when I execute:

```
ps aux | grep java
```

Per the comments in Ian's answer, I should be seeing 2 processes.

Comment: This bug still exists in 2.5.4, and documentation is still incorrect. There is no way to exit the grails interactive console while leaving the forked container running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs are misleading, you have to put that configuration line in `BuildConfig.groovy`, not `Config.groovy` (tried with version 2.2.1).

Comment: If you're right, it is not misleading. It is flat out wrong. ;o).  I'll give this a go and report back...

Answer (score 0):

Even in "forked" mode the app will still run in the foreground.  The point of forking is to run the Grails *application* in a separate process from the run-app *script* in order to isolate the app's classpath from that of the runner (e.g. if it needs to depend on different versions of certain core libraries).

Comment: That's not what the instructions say..."Note that in forked mode the grails process will exit and leave the container running in the background. To stop the server there is a new stop-app command:"  How would I issue the stop-app command if I'm still locked in?

Comment: @Gregg then the code disagrees with the documentation, it's definitely doing a `waitFor` on the forked process... You could run `stop-app` from another terminal, or since (looking at the script) all `stop-app` does is make an http request to `http://localhost:<port+1>` (i.e. 8081 if the app is on 8080) you could just do the same yourself from a browser.

Comment: Not doubting you, just doing my due diligence.  Can I confirm this somehow by looking at running processes?  For example, if I do a top, will I see 2 processes for a forked execution vs 1 for an un-forked execution?

Comment: @Gregg that's the idea yes.  In the forked case there should be a second `java` process whose main class is `org.grails.plugins.tomcat.fork.ForkedTomcatServer`

Comment: Hm, I'm only seeing a single java process via top and Activity Monitor.  Doing a ps aux | grep java, I only see one process.  I'm going to add this info to my question.